# tmux send-keys to vim has no effect when used with swap-pane

Tags: tmux, linux-ubuntu

I have a tmux window with 2 panes (pane-ids: 0 and 1). In the pane 0 there is vim launched. I want to fire a combination of two commands from tmux command-prompt:

```
:send-keys -t 0 "iabc" ; swap-pane -D
```

The keys `iabc` are to enter Insert mode in vim and type. It doesn't matter what they are - just intended to be input for vim. Unfortunately this doesn't work. The `swap-pane` does work but the sent keys are not "consumed" by vim until after I manually press some key in the vim's pane or call a separate `send-keys` again and then suddenly the "suspended" action takes effect. It looks like the vim's process cannot consume input because of swapping the containing pane at the same time.

Eventually I need a binding like: `bind-key s send-keys -t 0 "iabc" \; swap-pane -D` but I observed it behaved exactly the same on a command-prompt level.

I tried many different binding versions with multiple `send-keys`s and sequences and neither works so please don't suggest untested guesses because I've already wasted a whole lot of time for it :( I need to achieve it in a single `bind-key`. I'll appreciate any help or explanation of this failure.

The versions I'm using are:

- tmux 3.0a
- vim 8.1
- bash 5.0.17(1)
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Try throwing a redraw of some kind in there (like C-o C-L)

Comment: (I've used tpope's tmux plugin to do `:.Twrite {left}<CR>` to send commands to panes, including Vim commands to a pane running Vim, but I had to redraw sometimes to see the effects (esp. with cursor position).

Comment: What terminal emulator is running?

Comment: It's Mintty (WSL1, Windows 10)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble which app specifies C-o what does it do? you mean Jump to previous position in vim?

Comment: Your command was `iabc`, leaving you in insert mode; normal-mode C-L redraws the screen, so C-o C-L temporarily jumps to normal-mode from insert-mode for the single command C-L. If the command were `iabc<esc>` (use a literal escape, of course), then only C-L would be needed. The point was to tell Vim to redraw the screen; sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Oh, I get it. I'm not used to that meaning of C-o in Insert mode although it's great indeed. At least some side hint gained from that, thanks :P